# Linux startup script dependency issue

Tags: linux, init.d

I have a startup script in init.d that starts some process that depends on Redis server running. When init script executes on boot my process fails due to connection failure to Redis server. I have the following line in init script:

`# Required-Start: $all`

which as I understand should run this script as last in the sequence. I also tried `# Required-Start: $all +redis-server` and `# Required-Start: redis-server` but it didn't help.
Is it the case that services are executed in parallel so even though this script executes at the end its dependencies may not be fully running yet?